# Break command do nothing in .bat file

Tags: batch-file, breakpoints

`break /?` says:
If Command Extensions are enabled, and running on the Windows
platform, then the BREAK command will enter a hard coded breakpoint
if being debugged by a debugger.
`cmd /?` says:
Command Extensions are enabled by default. (I learned that we can manually enable/disable by `cmd /E:ON/OFF`)

Since Command Extensions are enabled by default, then

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (textfile.txt) do (
    echo %%f
    break
)
```

should work, but unfortunately not.

Why it's not working? What is the proper way to use `break` to set a breakpoint in the `for` loop?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "BREAK command will enter a hard coded breakpoint **if being debugged by a debugger**". What is the debugger that you are using?

Answer (score 1):

> If Command Extensions are enabled, and running on the Windows
>   platform, then the BREAK command will enter a hard coded breakpoint
>   if being debugged by a debugger.

You're not debugging it so naturally nothing happens. More info: [breakpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint) definition.
To exit from a loop use `goto` to an outside label:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in (textfile.txt) do (
    echo %%f
    goto break
)
:break
```